# WordPress JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am having a javascript error on my site http://fightgifs.com with this line of code in `footer.php`:

```
var main_menu=new main_menu.dd("main_menu");
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dd' of undefined

Anyone has an idea what to do ? The error is creating a problem for a javascript plugin (Shashin). Whole script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.carousel').elastislide({

    imageW  : 145,

    minItems    : 2,

    margin      : 10

});

var main_menu=new main_menu.dd("main_menu");

main_menu.init("main_menu","menuhover");

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `main_menu` you expected this to refer to is actually being [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

```
var main_menu = new main_menu.dd("main_menu");
```

Both mentions of `main_menu` actually refer to the local variable being declared, which will be `undefined` rather than an object with a `.dd()` method.

To avoid this, you'll have to rename one of them.

```
var menu = new main_menu.dd("main_menu");

menu.init("main_menu","menuhover");
```

Or, if you don't need the `var` afterwards, you can also skip it:

```
new main_menu.dd("main_menu")
    .init("main_menu","menuhover");
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, however now I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: main_menu is not defined`

Comment: @MartinLaumets Well, that depends on what `main_menu` was expected to be and what is supposed to be defining it. It might actually have a different name. It might be a property of another object rather than a global. If it's from a WordPress plugin, it could be that some the plugin's files aren't being included in the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Your code of `main_menu` object has a problem. Post your code related to main_menu or check code yourself.

Comment: it's also probably a bad idea to redefine the object to a variable . . .